# Undo close tab in Light Table

Tags: lighttable

i started to use Light Table for JavaScript and there is embedded browser. I would like to know how to restore this tab after closing it and having it pointing to file it was opened for.

THX

Answer (score 0):

You just need to hit `ctrl-space`to open the commands window and search for "Open current file in browser" while you have the file open in your current tab.

For convenience you may add a custom keybinding on your `user.keymap` file. To show it open the command window, search for "user keymap" and select it, and then paste this if empty or edit accordingly (this is the file format for version 0.7.2, upgrade to it before if your version is older).

```
[ 
[:editor "ctrl-5" :editor.open-current-file-in-browser ] 
]
```

and then on the commands window again hit `reload keymaps`